# Linq To Objects With DateTime Properties

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

If you have a collection of:

```
public class TestObj        
{        
    public DateTime Key { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

The collection might have a count of 20,000 TestObj objects. I need to query using `linq` on the `Key` (`DateTime`) from `DateTime t1` to `DateTime t2`. 
I also want to insert and delete from the collection.
I see that the SortedList has an `Add` and a `Remove` method. Is `SortedList` efficient way to handle this problem? I am thinking that a `List<T>` would have to traverse through the entire list to be sure of getting all objects with `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I suggest you to look at B-tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree
It has O(logn) in the worst cases of Index, Search, Delete and Insert tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry too much about performance of lists. 20,000 is nothing. If you have a list with billions of elements, then it might be more of a problem, but even then, optimization causes more problems than it solves.

If you want to make sure it doesn't matter, you can test it yourself:

```
var l = new SortedList<DateTime, TestObj>();
var key = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    var o = new TestObj();
    o.Key = key;
    key = key.AddDays(1);
    l.Add(o.Key, o);
}
var sw = new Stopwatch();
var date1 = new DateTime(1995, 5, 5);
var date2 = new DateTime(2010, 5, 5);
sw.Start();
var between = l.Where(x => x.Key >= date1 && x.Key <= date2).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(between.Count());
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Output is:

`5480` (number of elements filtered out) and
`00:00:00.0142387` (you wouldn't even notice)

Comment: Of course, this only applies if you're not filtering in a loop. Multiplication makes this a lot more complicated. But yeah, it's still a lot of work optimizing this correctly. It took *16 years* to get from first binary search implementation to one that didn't have bugs. Oh, did I say it didn't have bugs? That version still had a bug, only found *44 years later*. 1946 - 2006. And those guys were hard core mathematicians. They thought the 1962 version was *proven to work*.

Comment: @Luaan - That sounds interesting. Do you have a reference that I can look into it some more?

Comment: @Enigmativity References of references of references :D In Knuth's Sorting and Searching (section 6.2.1), he points out the errors in the first implementations. Jon Bentley had some interesting notes (some wrong IMO, but still interesting) in his Programming Pearls, and quoted Knuth's S&S. The final (hehe) bug was discovered by Joshua Bloch, who wrote the binary search code for JDK - http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html . The message is clear - be extremely careful about the invariants you assume.

Comment: @Luaan - Thanks - good reference. In those days who would have that much memory?!?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, exactly. Of course, there were still tricks - sparse arrays, procedural generation, searching in *files* and such... And possibly, the older algorithms *might* have been written for platforms that didn't overflow at all. But even if that were so, the message is still there - you can't just assume you can take the code, "translate" it to C and roll with it. In cases like this, the math really is a lot simpler than making it work on a computer. I mean, `127! / 126!` is obviously just `127`, right? :))